# How is 'onRestart()' different from 'onCreate()'?

Tags: android

I am learning about developing applications using Android and I think I understand when `onCreate()` and  `onRestart()` are called during an Activity's lifecycle.

The trouble is, both the functions seem to serve the same purpose, i.e., it seems that both the functions are supposed to the things that are a pre-requisite to `onStart()` (see: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) as both of them are the only functions called before `onStart()`.

The official guide docs do not describe `onRestart()` in a detailed manner (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#lc and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestart()).

What procedures should be performed differently (or not performed at all) in `onRestart()` as compared to `onCreate()`?

In short:

> What steps should be performed in `onRestart()` and **not** in
>   `onCreate()` and *vice versa* and what steps should be common to both
>   the functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: android activity lifecycle]

As you can see in the image above

`onCreate` is only called when `App` is **killed**

`onRestart` is called when the user come back to the activity

Examples of `onRestart`

- After pressing the home button, again when you open the app from a recent task list
- When your phone screen is off and is turned back on

You can perform several tasks which is totally depend on your needs;

Examples of use of `onRestart`

- Asking user to insert `pin` to continue using the app
- Validating user with server

Hope this will clear your doubts about `onRestart()`

Please comment if you need more help!

**PS:** Image is labeled for reuse but still, [link to image source](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/android/)

Comment: Please consider attributing the image source.

Answer (score 0):

**onCreate()** is a callback function that been called once per opening of the activity. It's responsible for creating the activity. Moreover, according to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#oncreate) onCreate() *is the basic application startup logic that should happen only once for the entire life of the activity.*

**onStart()** is the callback that indicates the view is now visible to the user.

**onResume()** is the callback that indicates that the user now can interact with the activity.

So now, the user might press the home button on his mobile which makes your current application gone. By pressing the home button, **onPause()** and **onStop()** called consecutively.

Here is the role of **onRestart()** occurs. when the user try to get back the activity gone, there is no need to create the activity again (by **onCreate()**) because it already exists, so it's directly goes for **onStart()** callback.

I hope this was clear enough

Comment: The answer you've posted was copied from the documentation site (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) without any attribution. Please consider quoting and attributing the source.

Comment: @MustafaKhaled I am sorry, this is still not clear. This does not answer the role of onRestart(). Your answer, in a way, indicates that `onRestart()` is redundant ("so it's directly goes for onStart() callback."). What steps should i put into `onCreate()` that I do not need in `onRestart()` and vice versa?

(Please consider giving a stub example)